# Testing report status swipe after sending an email

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I have automated more than 5 applications in Java with Selenium Webdriver + TestNG + Email helper.

Currently, I am facing one issue in one of the applications. After successfully done the execution the HTML report generated as well as the same report is sent to all teammates but few of the test case statuses are the swipe in mail. See the attached screenshot.

And due to this reason failed cases shows pass and pass cases are shows as failed. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

[TESTNG Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvAiR.png)

Comment: is it testng report or its another custom report?

Comment: It's a TestNG Report and after generating this report, we are sent this report via email to all teammates.

Comment: is TestNG report is good? as you said "few of the test case statuses are the swipe in mail" what script in Email helper you using need to cross check why this happening. with provided info its not possible to help you.